# How do I find a recipe for the New Years Treat of Kozenach?

Tags: honey

Many years ago (at least 50) my dear Babuska and Auntie used to make something called "Kozenach" on New Years Eve.  At the stroke of midnight our entire family would drink champagne and eat this wonderful desert.  This desert consisted of the best freshest pure honey my father could find from his beekeeper friends and walnuts that we all would crack open carefully so as not to get the shells in.  The women would prepare these 2 ingredients by cooking them together and spreading them on many plates because everyone ate this like it was the best thing in the world, it was.

I have looked all over the internet for recipes, asked friends, gone to church but couldn't find anything. Does anyone have any clue or has anyone experienced this wonderful sweet of my childhood called "Kozenach"?  Do I not have the right name? Is there something else like this I could search for?

This was a Russian dish but people of different ethnicities (Armenians, Russians, Germans, etc.,) also enjoyed it very much.  I have tried to find the elder women who are still alive who made it, but unfortunately their touch and memory is not there.  It is the same for homemade "halva" which is totally and unfortunately not the same that is sold in stores, pre-made or even made at the stores.  I used to make this but again, my memory and my own recipes are lost (this recipe is basically making a roux and adding sugar water).

Comment: Search for "Gozinakh" or "Gozinaki" and you should be successful. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gozinaki) Often, it's a problem with regional varieties and transcribing from Cyrillic into Latin letters. But remember: Recipe requests are usually off topic here...

Comment: And for future reference: If you can't find something by the proper name (or because the spelling is unclear), you can try with the main ingredients and a few other keywords. I googled "walnut honey russian candy" instead of your "Kozenach" -> worked like a charm.

Comment: I've edited this to simply ask how to find a recipe - or essentially, what it's actually called. That's a fine question to ask. We just don't want to get into the business of having a dozen people all posting variations on a recipe and arguing over which one's the good one :)

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help and info. I do have a Russian cookbook, but it is Russian and since my Mom can't translate anymore and I do not read in Russian, I spell as best as I can.  Unfortunately google is still a big mystery to me as well as the internet and I have no idea how I got on this site but, have bookmarked it.  Please take off bounty points of 50 Jefromi because I have no idea how to even though I have read and re-read and give them to yourself and 50 to Stephie.  Please do this for me because I will not be able to do it or figure it out. Sorry & Thank You Very Much

Comment: I had to learn more about Google and found "Armenian Gozinakh" and started experimenting.  Basically on the internet it was more like a peanut brittle but after some patience and love, I got it to the consistency I wanted which was softer and "spreadable". It set a bit, then we cut into triangles right on the plate and served.  Delicious.  Thank You All

Comment: Sadly, My Mama died a week ago. Tonight I decided to come back to to this site because she and I would always talk about it. I will inform you about Armenian Gozinakh because at Mamas luncheon I made the deserts and my friend volunteered me to go back and start baking and cooking for the Ladies Aide  bacand our Desert Fair, Paklava here you come back. Old world deserts will be back and I will tinker back here. Thank you all, you will be part of my salvation